# Get id details from another table in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the value of id from another table

I have a table world_match :

[image]

and teams_world:

[image]

I'm trying to get the id, date, the name of the home team and away team :

Expected:

- id: 1
- Date: 25/12/2022
- Home: Qatar
- Away: Ecuador

So currently, I have a problem with my sql:

```
SELECT id_match, date_debut, id_domicile, id_exterieur FROM match_world m INNER JOIN teams_world t ON m.id_domicile = t.id_equipe AND m.id_exterieur = t.id_equipe
```

Someone can explain me my problem in this sql request please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see what you want to accomplish, but you're going about it the wrong way. You need to join the `match_world` twice with the `teams_world` table, once for the home team and once of the away team.

```
SELECT 
  match_world.id_match, 
  match_world.date_debut, 
  team_home.nom AS home_nom, 
  team_away.nom AS away_nom
FROM 
  match_world 
INNER JOIN 
  teams_world AS team_home 
  ON match_world.id_domicile = team_home.id_equipe 
INNER JOIN 
  teams_world AS team_away 
  ON match_world.id_exterieur = team_away.id_equipe
```

You were quite close. Note also that I like to write my queries in a way that they are easy to read, on several line, with indentations, and no abbreviations. This does not impact performance.

*(query is untested, no guarantee of functionality given...)*

Comment: Thank you for your advice and your help. Got a problem: Notice: Undefined index: id_domicile. Do you think it's a problem in request or in my db ?

Comment: your screen shot and your query have id_domicile in word match, maybe a typo somewhere

Comment: @oxem: Yes, I would put it down to a typo, as nbk suggests above.

Comment: I try the request in phpmyadmin, it works good ! but the display is: id - date_debut - nom - nom. I'm doing this: echo $row["id_match"]. "- " . $row["date_debut"]. " -" . $row["nom"]. " -" . $row["nom"]. "; How can I dissociate the "nom" ?

Comment: @oxem I've changed my answer and added aliases for the names. You can now do: `echo $row["id_match"]. "- " . $row["date_debut"]. " -" . $row["home_nom"]. " -" . $row["away_nom"]. ";`.

Comment: I understand, thnak you for you time